HTML canvas game giving error cant import outside of a module
The file that isn't working is a js file and I'm trying to import a resource.js file to get the game objects loaded

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

If I remove that js import the same error pops up for my CSS stylesheet saying the same thing.
I'm on node 20.16.0 and I'm running the files in google chrome, but the error is happening even if I switch browsers.
I have looked through some forums and have made myself a live server which fixed my export problem I was having before this, but it didn't help with the import statement. The import statement I'm using is:
import {Resources} from "./src/resources.js"
import './src/style.css'

I have the CSS linked with this in the  area
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css"></link>

and I have the 2 js files linked with this:
<script src="src/resources.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

I've tried to flip the way I called the scripts in the html, I've tried calling both of them as modules or switching which of them was called as a module which resulted in an error saying it couldn't fetch the files.

The script that contains the import statements needs type="module". You don't need to load the same script with both import and <script>.

"I'm on node 20.16.0 and I'm running the files in google chrome"  Can you please clarify what's running server-side, what's running browser-side, and what's being bundled (if anything)?  If you're using any kind of framework, you should probably mention what that is too.

@Barmar thanks for the help, i removed the script call from the html file and just imported it in the main.js file and it fixed the issue i was having. I am getting a new error with the import for the CSS stylesheet saying something about how it failed to load and expected a js file, but i might make a separate question for that error. thanks for your help!

It makes no sense to import CSS into JavaScript. CSS is for HTML, not JS.
